# Compatibility Issues with WPF XBAP in IE versions (IE10/11)

Tags: wpf, xbap

We have been using XBAP in our application . We observed that BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript doesn't work in IE9 to talk to the javascript on the host page.
So with the help of XbapFTHelper.cs,  we resolved this issue for IE9. But again this solution doesnt work on IE10/IE11.
My aim here is to interact with the javascript files from the host page .
Is there any solution which will support all versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a blog post about how to get this to work without any hacks. I have tested it in IE9 and IE11.

[XBAP and Javascript with IE9 or newer - Solution for MissingMethodException problems](http://hotzblog.com/xbap-and-javascript-with-ie9-or-newer-solution-for-missingmethodexception-problems/)

Comment: Code is running well when XBAP and the parent site is on same server...But my XBAP is on different server and parent site is on different server then I am  getting 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' error on 
hostScript.document.AttachXBAPHandler(new XBAPHandler(this)); statement 
 because I am getting hostScript is NULL. Do u have any idea ??

Comment: I replied to your question in discussion at the blog.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is exactly what I want...its working well... :)